# How to suppress "warning: missing initializer" caused by Boost.Log and GCC 4.4?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

Can anyone tell me how to suppress the following warning message which is generated by Boost.Log and GCC 4.4.7? My project is built in C++11 mode (with `-std=c++0x` in GCC 4.4.7).

```
src/Logger.cc:7: warning: missing initializer for member ‘boost::log::v2_mt_posix::expressions::attribute_keyword<tag::severity, boost::phoenix::actor>::proto_expr_’
```

where `src/Logger.cc` is the source file of my logging class which is a wrapper of Boost.Log. Line 7 uses one of Boost.Log macros as follows. `Logger::ESeverityLevel` is an enum defined in `Logger.h`.

```
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(severity, "Severity", Logger::ESeverityLevel)
```

This macro can be expanded as follows.

```
namespace tag    {\
        struct severity :\
            public ::boost::log::expressions::keyword_descriptor\
        {\
            typedef Logger::ESeverityLevel value_type;\
            static ::boost::log::attribute_name get_name() { return ::boost::log::attribute_name("Severity"); }\
        };\
    }\
    typedef ::boost::log::expressions::attribute_keyword< tag::severity > severity_type;    const severity_type severity = {};
```

It looks that the initialization of `severity_type` makes this warning, while it is valid with Clang (Apple LLVM version 6.0).

An official example code of this macro can be found at 
http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.log#ex.log_05

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to disable the warning in GCC using it's [built-in `#pragma`s](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html), e.g.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push      // Save the current warning state
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-field-initializers" // Disable the warning you're getting

...
// offending code
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(severity, "Severity", Logger::ESeverityLevel)
...

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop        // Restore previous default behaviour
```

You can also disable this behaviour at the command line using the `-Wno-missing-field-initializers`.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick answer. It works. As my compiler is a bit too old GCC 4.4.7, I could not use `push` or `pop`. Instead, I re-enabled the warning right after the macro line by putting `#pragma GCC diagnostic warning`